# Speedometer doesn't work and transmission won't shift

Tags: automatic-transmission, shifting, gmc, speedometer, sierra

I have a 95 GMC Sierra with a 4.3 V6 and automatic transmission. The speedometer doesn't work and will not shift on it's own. I have replaced trans fluid and filter(no shavings or anything abnormal looking), replace speed sensor, unplugged speed sensor buffer, unplugged computer, checked all fuses and disconnected the battery all with no luck. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Does it shift if you start with the gear selector in low and move it up through the range manually as the vehicle speeds up?

Comment: It will shift 1st to 2nd and that's it